# SQL table creation code gives error

Tags: sql

could someone have a look at this for me, I can't seem to find why it is not working.

```
CREATE TABLE Person(
Person_ID int auto_increment NOT NULL,
Person_Type_ID int NOT NULL,
Create_Date datetime NOT NULL ,
Modify_Date datetime NOT NULL ,
First_Name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
Surname varchar(50) NOT NULL,
DOB date NOT NULL,
Gender char(1) NOT NULL CHECK (Gender ='f' OR Gender ='m'),
Archive char(1) NULL,
Allergies varchar(200) NOT NULL,
Dietry_Requirements varchar(200) NOT NULL,
Disabilities varchar(200) NOT NULL,
Medicine_Requirements varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    username varchar (30) NOT NULL,
password varchar (30) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_Person_ID PRIMARY KEY (Person_ID)
CONSTRAINT FK_Person_Type_ID FOREIGN KEY (Person_Type_ID)
REFERENCES Person_Type (Person_Type_ID));
```

Comment: What's the error? What's the RDBMS (MySQL? SQL Server? Oracle?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed a comma! This should work...

```
CREATE TABLE Person(
Person_ID int auto_increment NOT NULL,
Person_Type_ID int NOT NULL,
Create_Date datetime NOT NULL ,
Modify_Date datetime NOT NULL ,
First_Name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
Surname varchar(50) NOT NULL,
DOB date NOT NULL,
Gender char(1) NOT NULL CHECK (Gender ='f' OR Gender ='m'),
Archive char(1) NULL,
Allergies varchar(200) NOT NULL,
Dietry_Requirements varchar(200) NOT NULL,
Disabilities varchar(200) NOT NULL,
Medicine_Requirements varchar(200) NOT NULL,
username varchar (30) NOT NULL,
password varchar (30) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_Person_ID PRIMARY KEY (Person_ID),
CONSTRAINT FK_Person_Type_ID FOREIGN KEY (Person_Type_ID)
REFERENCES Person_Type (Person_Type_ID));
```